# How to COMPARE to two columns in different worksheet and add a new column to worksheet 2 in excel

Tags: excel

I have two worksheet WS1 (Project level sheet) and WS2 (task level sheet with a common column Project #. In WS 1 project # is unique and in WS 2 project # is at multiple places because it references to the tasks, so 1 project # has multiple tasks.

I want to add project id from WS1 to WS2 for the number of Project # repeated in WS2.

E.G.

Sheet 1
Project #   Project id  Project Name
12357              21                ABC
12234              34                XYZ
14567              43                DEF
15465              50                LMN

Sheet 2

Project #   Task Name
12357       ABC_Initial phase
12357       ABC_Recovery
12357       ABC_close out
14567       DEF_Business Process
14567       DEF_discussion
12234       XYZ_Testing
12234       XYZ-UAT
12234       XYZ_preprod
12234       XYZ_production
15465       LMN_CP

OUTPUT SHEET 3:
Project #   Project id  Task Name
12357               21      ABC_Initial phase
12357               21      ABC_Recovery
12357               21      ABC_close out
14567               43     DEF_Business Process
14567               43      DEF_discussion
12234               34       XYZ_Testing
12234               34         XYZ-UAT
12234               34       XYZ_preprod
12234               34      XYZ_production
15465               50           LMN_CP

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you want to add the Project ID from the first sheet as a new column in the second sheet, by looking it up based on the Project #? (I don't know what sheet 3 is for.)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to a new column in the second sheet and copy it down. Adjust the ranges accordingly. This will extract the Project ID from the first sheet (in column B) based on the the Project # in the second sheet (in column A).

```
=VLOOKUP($A6,Sheet1!$A$6:$B$112,2,0)
```